# How to convert this list in a given format?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a list like this:

```
  hello = [[<User: mr--adhikari>], [<User: mr--adhikari>], [<User: mr--adhikari>, <User: awesome>]]
```

I want to convert the list to look like this:

```
[['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari', 'awesome']]
```

Tried with:

```
re = [i.split(':')[1] for i in hello]
ref = [i.split('>')[0] for i in ref]
```

This works if I have only don't have two elements in a same list. I may or may not have two elements in a same list.

**Edit**:
My dynamic list:

```
   shared_username = ['[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>, <User: awesome>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]']

shared_username = [[y.lstrip('<User: ').rstrip('>') for y in x] for x in shared_username]
```

Result:

```
[['[', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'm', '', '-', '..so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `sts.lstrip` and `str.rstrip`:

Demo:

```
>>> strs = '[<User: mr--adhikari>]'
>>> strs = strs.lstrip('[<User: ')
>>> strs
'mr--adhikari>]'
>>> strs = strs.rstrip('>]')
>>> strs
'mr--adhikari'
```

Code:

```
>>> hello = [['<User: mr--adhikari>'], ['<User: mr--adhikari>'], ['<User: mr--adhikari>', '<User: awesome>']]
>>> [ [y.lstrip('<User: ').rstrip('>') for y in x] for x in hello ]
[['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari', 'awesome']]
```

**Update:**

```
>>> shared_username = ['[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>, <User: awesome>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]']

>>> [[y.lstrip('[<User: ').rstrip('>]') for y in x.split(', ')] for x in shared_username]
[['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari', 'awesome'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari']]
```

Demo:

```
strs = '[<User: mr--adhikari>, <User: awesome>]'
```

Split the string at `', '` first to get a list of string, now loop over this list and apply `str.lstrip`, `str.rstrip` as described above.

```
>>> strs.split(', ')
['[<User: mr--adhikari>', '<User: awesome>]']
```

## Update:

Using `regex`:

**Demo:**

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'User:\s([A-Za-z\-._/@]+)')
>>> strs = '[<User: sachitad>, <User: awesome>]'
>>> r.findall(strs)
['sachitad', 'awesome']
>>> strs1 = '[<User: mr--adhikari>, <User: awesome>]'
>>> r.findall(strs1)
['mr--adhikari', 'awesome']
>>> strs2 = '[<User: respect>]'
>>> r.findall(strs2)
['respect']
>>> strs = '[<User: sa@chi.tad>, <User: awe_so/me>]'
>>> r.findall(strs)
['sa@chi.tad', 'awe_so/me']
```

**Code:**

```
>>> shared_username = ['[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>, <User: awesome>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]']
>>> [r.findall(item) for item in shared_username]
[['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari', 'awesome'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari']]
```

Comment: `lstrip` is a bad idea. To quote the docs: "The chars argument is not a prefix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped". It works with this set of values but if one of the values were `[<User: respect>]` it would give you `pect>]`.

Comment: Sorry I have to unaccept this answer because your solution doesn't work in all cases. With a string like : strs = '[<User: sachitad>, <User: awesome>]', I get only achitad.

Comment: @user2032220 Does those name contain any other special character other than `-`?

Comment: The name might contain _ or - or / or . or @

Comment: Thank you so much for your update but still it doesn't work, because sometimes there might not be spaces after : [<User:sachitad>]

Comment: @user2032220 Use this regex then : `r = re.compile(r'User:\s*([A-Za-z\-._/@]+)')`

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, are the elements inside the nested lists strings or dictionaries? If you are not sure run the following to check the first: print type(hello[0][0])

UPDATE:

Here is an alternative, that formats the output in the way you requested originally (without 'User: '). Not the most concise syntax, but it seems to work:

```
def get_user_data(lst, strip_str):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        tmp = lst[i]
        for j in strip_str:
            if j in tmp:
                tmp = tmp.replace(j,'')
        tmp = tmp.split(',')
        new_list.append(tmp)
    return new_list

shared_username = ['[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>, <User: awesome>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]', '[<User: mr--adhikari>]']
new_list = get_user_data(shared_username,['<','>',' ','[',']','User:'])
print new_list
```

Output: [['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari', 'awesome'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari'], ['mr--adhikari']]

Comment: Thanks. I can't think of a pythonic way to do this in one or two lines, but it should be easy enough to write a function to handle it. Might the usernames contain any spaces, or will they always be strings without spaces similar to the above?

Comment: The answer given by @Ashwini Chaudhary already worked. Thanks